# Как запускать часть код бесконечно через некоторое время вместе с другим циклом?

Tags: python, циклы, tkinter

Есть у меня некоторый код , который я зациклил вот таким вот образом :

```
 while True:
     код
   time.sleep(10)
```

Также я использую графическую библиотеку tkinter , который также запускает цикл обработки событий   `mainloop()` который является обязателен .

Что у меня есть:

```
 while true:
       код

        код tkinter'a 
        mainloop()

    time.sleep(10)
```

Как видим код начинается , но на `mainloop()` он уже начинает бесконечно зацикливать код `tkinter'a`

**Задание**: *Мне нужно чтобы был зациклен мой код , плюс корректно работал код граф. библиотеки* `tkinter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте функцию, которая будет перезапускать себя кадые 10 секунд

```
def timeIntervalFunc() :
     код
   root.after(10000, timeIntervalFunc)

root = tk.Tk();
timeIntervalFunc()
root.mainloop()
```